# Is System Reserved a special type partition? If yes, how can I create one?

Tags: windows, partitioning

I recently moved from an old laptop to new but had to merge two hard disks into one. Old laptop had small SSD and a HDD. However the new laptop had SSD only.

So I tried cloning the old SSD disk, and then add the partition from the HDD but was not able to because MBR can only support four partitions.

I had issues with booting, so I had to create a FAT32 EFI partition.

To cut a long story short, I deleted both System Reserved and Recovery partitions.

The issue is that now my Windows Update fails with an error that points to a System Reserved partition being missing.

I tried to just create a NTFS partition labeled "System Reserved" but that did not help.

Is the "System Reserved" a special type of partition? How can I create one?

Best regards

Answer (score -1):

Old question but for reference I just recently saw this:

> Create the New Windows 7 System Reserved Partition Using Windows Disk
>   Management This information can be used to create the Windows 7 System
>   Reserved partition after you have installed Windows using only Windows
>   native disk management.
>
> The main advantage of the System Reserved partition, it adds a link to
>   WinRE (Windows Recovery Environment) to the F8 advanced boot options
>   in Windows 7 that can be accessed during PC startup to repair startup
>   errors if a Windows installer or a system repair disk isn't available
>   for use; it also creates a central location to store the boot files
>   needed to start Windows in a dual/multi boot situation and that makes
>   it very easy to replace/remove a single OS when needed.
>
> There must be at least one (1) Primary partition for creation/use as
>   the System Reserved partition will not function as intended from an
>   Extended partition; for further information on this requirement see
>   Option Two #2 below.

https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/119151-system-reserved-create-using-disk-management.html

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.